# SELECT FROM table WHERE lang = :preferred OR lang = :default

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a simple table with a language variable and a content field.

```
------------------------
|  lg    |   content   |
------------------------
|  en    |  Hello      |
------------------------
|  es    |  Hola       |
------------------------
```

I can't be sure that I have the Spanish language in this table so I simply need to select from the table where the value is either `'es'` or `'en'`. I have been researching and found SQL `ISNULL()`, `NVL()`, `IFNULL()` and `COALESCE()` Functions. I have been looking at nested `IF ELSE` SQL `SELECT` statements, but I really need to know how is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: How can you tell that "Hello" and "Hola" are equivalent in different language? (i.e., what if you have additional content?) Is there some ID to the content?

Comment: i want to fetch `LIMIT 1` and get `$row['lg'] = 'es'`, `$row['content'] = 'Hola'`

Comment: @Sachu I have tried that one, but is seems to fetch in alphabetic order so if I limit to 1 then it will only return en, before it returns es.

Comment: @Mureinik This tables primary key is the `lg`. There can only be written a language specific content once. Therefor when i look in it I should be able to search for either da, de, fr,es,it and while doing so, if the value does not exists in this lanuage, then always return the english value insted.

Comment: @Dimser so I think you don't even need a coalesce-like expression. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the clarification in the comment that `lg` is the primary key, it would be much easier to select the rows with a custom order and `limit` clause:

```
SELECT   content
FROM     myable
WHERE    lg IN ('es', 'en')
ORDER BY FIELD (lg, 'es', 'en')
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: This is definitley the simplest wayto achieve it.. I had been dealing with `lg IN ('es', 'en') LIMIT 1`, but because mysql automatically ordered alphabetically, it always returned `en` before `es`. I should have known about the custom orderby.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make a cross join between the table and itself, so that you get the results side by side. Then you can use `coalesce` to get the desired value.

Example:

```
select
  coalesce(es.content, en.content, 'No translation') as content
from
  TheTable es
  cross join TheTable en on en.id = 42 and en.lg = 'en'
where
  es.id = 42 and es.lg = 'es'
```

Comment: Can I do this without an `id` field?

Comment: @Dimser: Yes, of course, just omit that condition. I was thinking that you were storing more than one phrase in the table.